# Why do Visual Studio Code error insights in c++ Show in a different language than the default one?

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-c++

How do I fix the fact that even though my main display language is set to English, my error insights are still shown in Polish while using the C++ extension only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that this is an error within the extension. All you need to do to solve it is:

- Try changing language to a different one and then back to English.
- If that didn't work open you file browser and go to:

> C:\Users<>.vscode\argv.json

It probably will look like this:

```
// This configuration file allows you to pass permanent command line arguments to VS Code.
// Only a subset of arguments is currently supported to reduce the likelihood of breaking
// the installation.
//
// PLEASE DO NOT CHANGE WITHOUT UNDERSTANDING THE IMPACT
//
// NOTE: Changing this file requires a restart of VS Code.
{
// Use software rendering instead of hardware accelerated rendering.
// This can help in cases where you see rendering issues in VS Code.
// "disable-hardware-acceleration": true,
// Enabled by default by VS Code to resolve color issues in the renderer
// See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/51791 for details
"disable-color-correct-rendering": true,
// Allows to disable crash reporting.
// Should restart the app if the value is changed.
"enable-crash-reporter": true,
// Unique id used for correlating crash reports sent from this instance.
// Do not edit this value.
"crash-reporter-id": "your-id"
}
```

In the file you probably will not see a phrase: ""locale": "en-us"" or you will see it but it will not be "en-us" but your error language. To fix it insert your "locale" like this:

```
// This configuration file allows you to pass permanent command line arguments to VS Code.
// Only a subset of arguments is currently supported to reduce the likelihood of breaking
// the installation.
//
// PLEASE DO NOT CHANGE WITHOUT UNDERSTANDING THE IMPACT
//
// NOTE: Changing this file requires a restart of VS Code.
{
// Use software rendering instead of hardware accelerated rendering.
// This can help in cases where you see rendering issues in VS Code.
// "disable-hardware-acceleration": true,
// Enabled by default by VS Code to resolve color issues in the renderer
// See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/51791 for details
"disable-color-correct-rendering": true,
// Allows to disable crash reporting.
// Should restart the app if the value is changed.
"enable-crash-reporter": true,
// Unique id used for correlating crash reports sent from this instance.
// Do not edit this value.
"crash-reporter-id": "your-id",
"locale": "en-us"
}
```

REMEMBER NOT TO EDIT CRASH REPORTER ID